# Power series Confusion on the definition

Tags: convergence-divergence, power-series

> let a power series be:$$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n\left(x-a\right)^n $$
>
> Then **there exists an R** with 0<=R<=infinity **such that**
>
> 1. the series converge if $\;|x-a| \le R\;$
> 2. the series diverges if $\;|x-a| > R\;$

Now the above statement is **False** in my homework correction but I do not understand **why?**

Comment: Is it because of the <= sign in |x-a| <= R which I have read in my classe definition is only a < sign?
Because the <= would mean it converges also for the boundaries of my convergence interval which is not necessarily true. Is that the expected reasoning?

Comment: @So It may depend on **what** were you asked: was it about the *radius of convergence* of a power series? Then yes, it is wrong for the weak inequaity, and perhaps it needs more explanation.

Comment: The series may or may not converge on the boundary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take this simple on for example:

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n$$

it has radius of convergence $R=1$ by the ratio test, but, at $x=-1$, we get

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n$$

which doesn't even pass the term test.  The correct modified statement is that

Converges: $|x-a|<R$

Unknown: $|x-a|=R$

Diverges: $|x-a|>R$

Answer (score 0):

On the circle $|x-a|=R$, it is possible for the series to converge on some points and not converge on others. Wikipedia has examples relating to [**convergence on the boundary**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius_of_convergence#Convergence_on_the_boundary).